# aspx Create Wizard Control assign Role

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a create user wizard control

then I've added an event "Created User"

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

and when I want to assign a role using this :

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, "Members");
```

it says that Roles do not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the role does not exist you can create it first using the ASP.NET Configuration Tool in Visual Studio or with a line like this in the code behind:

```
Roles.CreateRole("Members");
```

Comment: http://s23.postimg.org/qoauokz4r/image.jpg

here I uploaded a quick image of what is wrong, maybe I made myself unclear, thanks for help!

Comment: Oh, in that case you are probably missing this: using System.Web.Security;

Comment: Thats fixed it!

thank you and have a nice day! 

p.s "sadly can't upvote your answer" dont have permissions yet ^^ :\

Comment: You are welcome, I think you can still mark it as the answer though.